# DataGridViewAutoFilterTextBox displaying small number of items

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)#initialization) and the library included in the demo project I have setup Excel-like autofiltering on a datagridview.

However on columns where there are not many distinct values, only one or two rows are displayed:

[image: autofilter]

In this example, there are actually 3 or 4 values in the filter list that the user could select but only two rows are displayed and the rest you must scroll to find.

I've been unable to find where the height of the list box is set. Any can anyone point out where I can change/set this?

Comment: I think the real question is: *why are your filters only showing 1 or 2 options when you are expecting 3?*  I would suggest exploring that line of reasoning then updating your post with your more focused findings.

Comment: The filters do show the other results, you just have to scroll down to view them. I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this may be what you are looking for.

In the documentation is the following paragraph:

**The SetDropDownListBoxBounds Method**

The `SetDropDownListBoxBounds` method initializes the size and location of the drop-down list. 
The preferred size depends primarily on the `dropDownListBox` contents, which are the formatted values stored in the Keys collection of the filters dictionary. The `SetDropDownListBoxBounds` method first calls the `Graphics.MeasureString` method for each filter value. For each value, the width is stored if it is wider than all previous values, and the height is added to an accumulating total height for all values. The results are then *used to determine the preferred size*.

The *preferred height is the smallest of the following values*:

- The accumulated height of all filter values.
- The user-specified maximum height as calculated from the
  `DropDownListBoxMaxLines` property value.
- The available height of the `DataGridView` control client area.